# Log4j roll file for each execution

Tags: log4j

I have a Java project using a log4j appender that works as a batch.

I would like it to roll a file for each execution.

Log4j offers to roll a file either by a period of time (`DailyRollingFileAppender`), or by file length (`RollingFileAppender`), which is good for continuously-on applications, like in Java EE, but not so good for a batch.

Is there a way to manually trigger the file rolling?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, it was easy, I just had to do the following :

```
for (Enumeration<Appender> e = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            Appender a = e.nextElement();
            if (a instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
                ((RollingFileAppender) a).rollOver();
            }
        }
```

at the beginning of the batch...